# Azure Timer Function not Running

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I have an Azure Function with a Timer trigger. The schedule is "0 0 18 * * MON-FRI". I can run it manually but it does not fire automatically. I've seen some answers that say the App Service Plan cannot be "classic" but I do not see that option. The App Service plan for my Function app is Consumption based. Any advice?

Here is function.json:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.24",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "schedule": "0 0 18 * * MON-FRI",
      "useMonitor": true,
      "runOnStartup": false,
      "name": "myTimer"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/MyApp.dll",
  "entryPoint": "MyApp.ProcessOptions.Run"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's in an `App Service Plan`, you need to make sure that **Always On** is enabled.

In `Consumption` mode, there is no such thing as `Always On`. Instead, your Function App should **be automatically woken up when a timer is due**. For this to work, your triggers need to be `synced`, which normally happens automatically in various scenarios:

a) If you're using the portal to make a change to a function

b) If you deploy your Function App using msdeploy, Kudu git deploy, or Kudu's zipdeploy (`/api/zipdeploy`)

c) If you click the little Refresh icon next to your Function App name in the Portal

**Note**: **By default, the schedule uses UTC time**, so be aware of this when setting a daily schedule (it doesn't matter if it fires hourly).
You can change this to us a specific time zone by setting `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE`. See [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#set-the-time-zone) for more info.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Investigating-and-reporting-issues-with-timer-triggered-functions-not-firing).